# Time complexity of an algorithm with two loops and two recursive calls

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

Here is an algorithm of sorting an array with two recursive calls.I have tried to calculate its time complexity roughly but not sure.I know that two for loops will take n+n times but what to do with recursive calls and how can i calculate them?
 Any one can help in calculating in simple mathematical way.

```
MySort (a[1..n] , n) {

         If (n <= 2) {
            If (first element > second) && (n = 2) then do
               { Interchange a[1] & a[2]; }
         End if
         }
         Else
         { Assign value to min and max by very first element of array.
         for (i : = 1 to n) do 
            { If (a[i] > max) then
              max = a[i]; 
         Else if (a[i] < min) then
                  min = a[i]; //Get max and min element from the array. }
         End for
         Calculate MID value of the MAXIMUM & MINIMUM element found. 
         For i : = 1 to n do 
         {
            If(a[i] < mid) then { Increment Count1 by 1; and P[Count1]=a[i] }
            Else if (a[i] > mid) then { Increment Count2 by 1; and Q[Count2]=a[i] } 
    //Divide the major array to sub-arrays; 
    //Count1 and Count2 are counters to make check on the size of sub-arrays generated. 
             }
        End for
        MySort (P, Count1);
           MSort (Q, Count2); }
        End if}
```

Comment: Please format properly, with indentations, one statement per line. It's unreadable as is.

Comment: I can't see where min, max, count1, count2 are initialized and how mid is calculated, so this will most likely crash.

Comment: BTW. I can't see two nested loops; and two nested loops don't necessarily mean O (n^2) - it depends on the loop.

Comment: its not a c++ code its pseudo code.Assign value to min and max by very first element of array.min, max, count1, count2 are explained where they are used

Comment: The loops are not nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two loops followed by two recursive calls. Ideally, each call would halve the size of the input, resulting in n/2 values. This gives a recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = n + n + T(n/2) + T(n/2)
T(n) = 2n + 2T(n/2)
```

This matches the last row of the table given on the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) page:

```
T(n) = O(nlogn)
```

If the input input is not evenly divided each call, then it instead takes n^2 time, as the size could possibly only be reduced by 1 each call:

```
T(n) = 2n + T(n-1) + T(1)
T(n) = nT(1) + 2n + 2(n-1) + 2(n-2) + ...
T(n) = O(n^2)
```

Comment: thanks alot @fgb for your help,with each recursive call,the input pass through two loops .one loop divides the array and second loop just maintained the pointers to the last element of the divided array .can you please explain this answer in detail . i guess you used substitution method here . "T(n) = 2n + T(n-1) + T(1)
T(n) = nT(1) + 2n + 2(n-1) + 2(n-2) + ...
T(n) = O(n^2)"